# Adding Custom Objects in Xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, controls

OK, this is the question :

- We all know `Object Library`, with all the controls in it
- How could I add a custom object into that list? (e.g. Under "Custom Objects")

I've read the following, but I still can't get it to work (Xcode 4.2 on Snow Leopard) :

> **Adding Custom Objects to the Library**
>
> Although you normally drag items out of the Library window and into
>   your user interface, you can also drag your custom configurations of
>   those objects back into the Library window. Doing this lets you
>   retrieve those custom objects later without having to reconfigure
>   them.
>
> To add a custom object to the library, do the following:
>
> 1. In your window, configure the object as you would like it.
> 2. Press and hold the Option key and drag the object to the Library window.
> 3. In the organization pane of the Library window, drop the object on the Custom Objects group or on a custom group you created. Interface
>      Builder prompts you for information about the dropped object.
> 4. Fill in the information about your object and press OK.
>
> You can use this technique to drag one object or a group of objects.
>   When dragging more than one object, the entire group becomes a single
>   item in the Library window. Dragging that item back out of the library
>   creates all of the original objects.
>
> The items you add to the library persist between Interface Builder
>   sessions so that you can use them over and over again. To remove a
>   custom item from the Library window, do the following:
>
> 1. Select the Custom Objects group in the library to see the items in that group.
> 2. Select your custom item.
> 3. Press the Delete key.
>
> You must remove custom items from the Custom Objects group in order to
>   remove them from the Library window. Removing items from your custom
>   group folders removes them from the group but not the library.
>
> In addition to adding custom configurations of objects to the library,
>   you can also add entirely new objects to the library through an
>   Interface Builder plug-in. Plug-ins are typically used in situations
>   where you want to be able to configure and edit the attributes of your
>   custom classes. For more information, see “Using Plug-ins to Integrate
>   New Objects into the Library.”

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had an email exchange with an XCode Engineer who works at Apple specifically about the issue of "Custom Objects" in Interface Builder in XCode 4, and in his own words said that that menu option is "nonfunctional".  Those are his exact words, and he is also one of the presenters on the WWDC 2012 videos that Apple provides to help developers.  Not that this was his fault, but I was very disappointed to see this reply.

I hope they rectify this in later versions of XCode, as this would be excellent functionality to implement.  In the mean time, I would suggest using the code snippet library as a work around.

All the best in your iOS development efforts :-)